# Finding greatest common divisor

Tags: javascript

The function below takes two integers and calculates the greatest common divisor (gcd):-

```
function mygcd(x, y) {
  while(y) var t = y, y = x % y, x = t;
  return x;
}
```

I've run through a load of test cases and stepped through the code to see how it comes to its result, but I'm absolutely stumped in terms of the method - can anybody explain to me in simple terms how this works, and how the while loop eventually returns the GCD of the two values x and y?

NOTE: I do understand how the code itself works - what I want to know is how the calculations eventually return the correct result.

Comment: This is [Euclid's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), derived about 2500 years ago.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mathematics, not programming.

Comment: @Barmar true but a good proof of the algorithm is pretty cool. :)

Comment: @Barmar _sure_ it's programming, just because something is abstract (how does an algorithm work?) doesn't mean it's not a real programming problem.

Comment: @Pointy Sure, but that proof would be on-topic for math.SE, not SO.

Comment: Apologies - I didn't know this was more of a mathematics question, and haven't heard of Euclid's method.  I guess I managed to get an answer, at least!!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum He said he understands how the code works, he doesn't understand the mathematical basis.

Comment: @Barmar I DO understand the mechanism of the code, but not how it eventually gets to the result.  I would argue this is perhaps both a mathematics and a programming question...

Comment: @Barmar yeah, that's just saying he understands the _syntax_ - that is what `%` does, what `while` is and what `return` is and so on. There are a lot of code bits where I understand all the parts but not the algorithm. Algorithmic questions are definitely on topic here - especially ones about common algorithms (finding the GCD is a real problem and an knowing why an efficient way to calculate it works is legit) - and indeed, there is a highly voted duplicate.

Comment: Euclid didn't know anything about computers when he came up with the algorithm. Asking how to calculate it efficiently would be a programming question, but asking how the algorithm works is pure math.